# How to pause while condition is false

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game, and I want to have a pause between one condition being true and an expression being run. The commented line below shows you where I want the pause, and the ***kind*** of pause I want is like this (which doesn't work):

```
while (bullet.yPos >= 0) {}; //Tried, failed
```

So I want my code to stop ***while*** `bullet.yPos` is greater than or equal to 0, and then continue when `bullet.yPos` is less than 0.

```
bullet.hidden = true;
//I want the pause here, and the line below to be executed when bullet.yPos is less than 0
bullet.hidden = false;
```

How should I do this?

EDIT: Here is the relevant method:

```
check: function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.aliens.length; i++) {

        var item = this.aliens[i];

        if ((bullet.lockedXPos >= item.xPos) && (bullet.lockedXPos <= item.xPos + this.size) && (bullet.yPos >= item.yPos) && (bullet.yPos <= item.yPos + this.size)) {

            item.hit = true;
            bullet.hidden = true;
            while (bullet.yPos >= 0) {};
            bullet.hidden = false;


        }

    }

},
```

Comment: Games run in forever loops (think `while(true)`). Decisions are based on logic. Within your main game loop check if `bullet.yPos < 0` ... if so apply whatever it is you're trying to do. If not, do nothing.

Comment: You could use a `Promise` that resolves when the value is appropriate.

Comment: @jhpratt Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: I'd need a bit more context to be able to do so properly.

Comment: @jhpratt Better now?

Comment: @JBDouble05 Not quite enough, but I'll give a text explanation of what to do :)

Comment: Hopefully that helps! It's not as difficult as you'd think, and takes advantage of the event loop, rather than eating up the CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Promise` along with the instance. I'm simplifying here, but the general idea is there.

`const yGreaterThanZero, { resolve } = new Promise();`

Now, in the method you've provided, you can use `await yGreaterThanZero`, which does exactly what you'd expect

```
check: async function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.aliens.length; i++) {

        var item = this.aliens[i];

        if ((bullet.lockedXPos >= item.xPos) && (bullet.lockedXPos <= item.xPos + this.size) && (bullet.yPos >= item.yPos) && (bullet.yPos <= item.yPos + this.size)) {

            item.hit = true;
            bullet.hidden = true;
            // while (bullet.yPos >= 0) {};
            await yGreaterThanZero; // this bit here is key
            bullet.hidden = false;

        }

    }

},
```

Additionally, where you update `bullet.yPos`, you'll want to add the following:

`if (bullet.yPos >= 0) resolve();`

Of course, the variable names should be semantic, so you shouldn't just call it `resolve`. However, that should suffice to wait for a certain condition, provided that you're also telling JS *when* that condition occurs.

Important note: The function was made `async`, so you'll need to adjust other bits of code where you're using it, so you're awaiting (and awaiting those functions as necessary).

Comment: How can I make the function named ***and*** async? Is it possible? How would I call this function if it doesn't have a name?

Comment: Sorry, I pulled that bit out. Just use `async function` where you would use `function`.

Comment: Where would I put the constant?

Comment: I presume you're defining this inside of a class, so making it a class field would be appropriate. Just somewhere local enough that it's visible to the necessary functions, but no more.

Comment: So I could put it inside the `check` function?

Comment: If that's where you're checking the position, then that's where you'll want to resolve the Promise there, but initialize it in a parent scope.

Comment: So put the constant in the object that `check` is inside? Or put the constant on a global level?

Comment: Not global, globals are normally bad :) Are these in a class? That's where I'd recommend putting it.

Comment: This method is inside an object, but I'm unsure how to declare a constant inside an object.

Comment: Just like the function! `{ promiseThing: new Promise() }`

Comment: So declaring the constant in an object is just `pause: new Promise()`?

Comment: Yup! Then call `pause.resolve()`. And reset it with a new Promise when appropriate, of course.

Comment: So when you say reset it, you mean once I've done whatever I need to do after the `pause` has been `resolve()`d, I just go `this.pause = new Promise()`?

Comment: Yup, that's what you'd want to do.

Comment: Yeah, async/await is a weird thing that takes quite a bit of getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `spin loop` in javascript (which is the type of loop you've written), no other code will end up executing. Ever. Just the code in the loop. That is because javascript is (generally) single threaded, so until a function returns, no other functions can run.

So in this case, you need restructure your code. One common way is to have a main loop that calls other functions every second or so (usually faster than that, usually once per frame). Then, you would rewrite your code to like this:

```
//in main loop
…
let bullet = createBullet() // makes a hidden bullet
handleBullet(bullet)
…

function handleBullet(bullet) {
  if (bullet.yPos >= 0) return
  bullet.hidden = false
}
```

This is just one possible and simplified answer, and there are many techniques and patterns you can use to structure your code more effective.

However, the key is to remember that if you need to "wait" and you are using a main loop, what you really want to do is skip the part of the code until that needs to wait, until the condition is true, but make sure *everything else* keeps working.

Comment: The easiest way to wait is by using `await`. Just saying :)

Comment: Normally I would be all for that (I love async / await), but the problem is triggering the promise resolution. you still need to check the main loop for the bullet position, and then trigger the resolve. So here, it actually seems more appropriate to not use an async function, because you gain very little from it. What is really needed is to split things up, so that the bullet portion check is separate from the collision check.  One option is to register events on changes of the data model, and run functions there. but that is a whole book of explanation, probably.

Comment: Ooh! this would actually be really fun to implement in [mobx](https://mobx.js.org)! You could use that to easily get the event driven changes you'd need. But it takes a couple days to understand what mobx is doing, although what it does is really neat and powerful.